# Filter data.table whether date-type column contains month

Tags: r, data.table

I have a lot of outliers in the months of January and December, hence I want to exclude them for now. Here's my `data.table`:

```
> str(statistics2)
Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  1418 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ status: chr  "hire" "normal" "hire" "hire" ...
 $ month : Date, format: "1993-01-01" "1993-01-01" ...
 $ NOBS  : int  37459 765 12 16 24 17 2 12 2 11 ...
```

I tried to create a condition that checks the month, but I get the following error.

```
format(statistics2['month'], "%m")
Error in `[.data.table`(statistics2, "month") : 
  typeof x.month (double) != typeof i.month (character)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your question specifically asks about `data.table`, there is a set of lubridate-like functions built into the `data.table` package (load the package and type `?month`, for instance). You don't need `format(...)` or `lubridate`.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(status=c("hire","normal","hire"),
                 month=as.Date(c("1993-01-01","1993-06-01", "1993-12-01")),
                 NOBS=c(37459,765,12))
DT
#    status      month  NOBS
# 1:   hire 1993-01-01 37459
# 2: normal 1993-06-01   765
# 3:   hire 1993-12-01    12

DT[!(month(month) %in% c(1,12))]
#    status      month NOBS
# 1: normal 1993-06-01  765
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `statistics2` is a data.frame

```
statistics2 <- data.frame(status=c("hire","normal","hire"),
    month=as.Date(c("1993-01-01","1993-06-01", "1993-12-01")),
    NOBS=c(37459,765,12)
)
```

then you should use

```
format(statistics2[["month"]], "%m")
# [1] "01" "06" "12"
```

(note the double brackets -- otherwise you're returning a list which `format()` cannot correctly interpret).

If `statistics2` is a data.table

```
statistics2dt <- data.table(statistics2)
```

then I would have thought `statistics2dt['month']` would have returned a different error, but the correct syntax in that case is

```
format(statistics2dt[, month], "%m")
# [1] "01" "06" "12"
```

(no quotes and a comma)

Answer (score 0):

You could use lubridate to extract the months and exclude those from the data frame:

```
require(lubridate)

rm(list = ls(all = T))

set.seed(0)
months <- round(runif(100, 1, 12), digits = 0)
years <- round(runif(100, 2013, 2014), digits = 0)
day <- round(runif(100, 2, 25), digits = 0)

dates <- paste(years, months, day, sep = "-")

dates <- as.Date(dates, "%Y-%m-%d")
NOBS <- round(runif(100, 1, 1000), digits = 0)

statistics2 <- cbind.data.frame(dates, NOBS)

months <- month(statistics2$dates)

excJanDec <- statistics2[-which(months %in% c(1, 12)) ,]
```